# The output image after cropping is larger than the original size

Tags: c#, image-processing

When I crop an Image using Bitmap.Clone() it creates output larger than the original image Size
The Original size is : 5 M
and the Output Cropped image is : 28 M

How can I make cropping without losing quality and with no large size?
My code is :

```
private static Image cropImage(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
{
  var bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
  Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea, bmpImage.PixelFormat);
  img.Dispose();
  bmpCrop.Save(@"D:\Work\CropImage\CropImage\crop.jpg",bmpImage.RawFormat );
  return (Image)(bmpCrop);
}

 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string sourceimg = @"D:\Work\Crop Image\CropImage\4032x5808.jpg";
            Image imageoriginal = Image.FromFile(sourceimg);
            int HorX,HorY,VerX,VerY;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter X 1 Cor. ");
            HorX=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Y 1 Cor. ");
            HorY=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter X 2 Cor. ");
            VerX=int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Y 1 Cor. ");
            VerY= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(HorX,HorY,VerX,VerY);
            cropImage(imageoriginal, rect);
        }
```

Comment: plz add some code barracks!

Comment: what format is the originale Image?

Comment: Where do you create the `Rectangle cropArea`?
What's the code?

Comment: Try to save as `Jpg` instead of `RawFormat`

Comment: what's your input for `HorX,HorY,VerX,VerY` - please consider that their real meaning is `X,Y, width from left to right, height from top to bottom`? also you have little typo in 4th string -it should be `("Enter Y 2 Cor. ");`

Comment: yes this is my Input X,Y, width from left to right, height from top to bottom

Comment: then please post actual numbers you provide for rectangle as your sample works very well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are saving the image as a bitmap, not a jpg, or png which is probably your input format. Change the format type and you will see the file size plummet!

This code sample should help you set the quality:-

```
var qualityEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
var quality = (long)<desired quality>;
var ratio = new EncoderParameter(qualityEncoder, quality );
var codecParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
codecParams.Param[0] = ratio;
var jpegCodecInfo = <one of the codec infos from ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders() with mime type = "image/jpeg">;
bmp.Save(fileName, jpegCodecInfo, codecParams); // Save to JPG
```

Comment: I tried to Save the Output as jpg or png and the same problem

Comment: The Format of Original image is "jpg"

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't need to worry about reducing quality when cropping as you simply save part of the original image with 1:1 ratio.

Your sample works fine - problem must be in `Rectangle` input part. As your variable names are confusing I would like to recommend reading about it at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wcdy991.aspx).

To be sure, just initialize your rectangle (assume that your image is greater than 1000x900 ) with `new Rectangle(200,100,800,800);` This will crop region starting from `200`th pixel from the left and `100`th pixel from the top with width and height equal to `800` pixels.

Final quality will remain the same and image size will be smaller.